# looking for a word or expressing to express matching, symmetric

Tags: word-choice, sentence, computing, technology

Background:

> A packet has a source IP and a destination IP.
>       I set the source IP as `10.0.0.3`.
>       The destination IP can be set as `10.0.0.1`, `127.0.0.1` or `138.9.32.4`.
>       These 3 IPs belong to the same computer.

My sentence is

> The destination IP can be set as `10.0.0.1`,  `127.0.0.1` or `138.9.32.4`,
>       but here we choose 10.0.0.1 for **formality**.

My aim is to describe the reason why we choose `10.0.0.1` as the destination.
I just want to express that the reason is `10.0.0.1` looks symmetric, matching, comfortable or whatever when it is matched with the source IP `10.0.0.3`.

I think ***formality*** is not suitable here. 
How to modify the sentence to express the reason? it is really abstract

Comment: Maybe ... "but we chose 10.0.0.1 for its symmetry?

Comment: Given the small amount of information you provided, I can't think of any technical reason for that choice. Routing decisions are only based on technical conditions (e.g., shortest path), not aesthetics.

Comment: If it is to help the reader quickly identify it because it is so similar to the source IP, you can consider it a memory aid or mnemonic.

Comment: You seem to mean *format* not 'formality.' "...we choose `10.0.0.1` for its matching format."

Answer (score 1):

I would say you chose 10.0.0.1 "for the sake of clarity" or maybe "for the sake of simplicity" or even "for the sake of formality".

Comment: Yes, but in OP's formal/technical context, just plain **for simplicity** is perfectly adequate.

Answer (score 0):

I think your consideration for choosing 10.0.0.1 over the others is not really relevant to your text, or is it? At least *I* don't see a reason why you have chosen that address other than a private, aesthetic reason. So I don't see why you should mention that. I would just say "we chose x". If the reason is indeed relevant to your text, then you'll have to explain why.

Answer (score 0):

> 10.0.0.1 was chosen by the method of convenience and influenced by symmetric and mnemonic properties.

In other words, any of the listed choices were valid, but the selected choice was easiest to use.  Credit to the commenters.